# Сохранение промежуточного результата и вывод окончательного

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Есть таблица, которая использует библиотеку быстрого поиска fuzzysearch. Этот поиск по вводу символов формирует новую таблицу, отображая результаты поиска.

Дописано на js, чтобы возле ключевой ячейки (номер строки) появлялся чекбокс, при нажатии на который результаты выбора суммируются в поле #Number ("Результаты поиска: 1, 5, 15" и т.п.).

Вот сам код:

```
var options = {
  valueNames: ['number', 'name']
};

var userList = new List('users', options);
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('td.number').prepend('<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></input>')
  $('.checkbox').on('click', function() {
    ids = $.map($('.checkbox:checked'), function(checkbox, index) {
      return $(checkbox.closest('td')).text()
    })
    $('#Number').val(ids.join(', '))
  })
})
```

Проблема в том, что это все работает, на текущей сформированной таблице. Как только я введу новые символы в поле поиска, которые изменят таблицу, все новые чекбоксы стирают старые. 
Поэтому ищу решение, которое сможет все результаты сохранять сначала в хранилище, независимо от того, какая сейчас таблица сформирована, и будет выводить в поле #Number уже конечный результат.

П.с. В js я очень новичок) Прошу помощи)

Весь код:

```js
var options = {
  valueNames: ['number', 'name']
};

var userList = new List('users', options);
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('td.number').prepend('<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></input>')
  $('.checkbox').on('click', function() {
    ids = $.map($('.checkbox:checked'), function(checkbox, index) {
      return $(checkbox.closest('td')).text()

    })
    $('#Number').val(ids.join(', '))
  })
})
```

```css
.list {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#users {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
}
.list td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #eee;
}
td.name {
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
}
#searchbox input {
  border: none!important;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 3px 5px!important;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#searchbox input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #aaa;
}
.sort {
  padding: 8px 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #28a8e0;
  height: 30px;
}
.sort:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #1b8aba;
}
.sort:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.sort:after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  right: -5px;
}
.sort.asc:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  right: -5px;
}
.sort.desc:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
  right: -5px;
}
#searchbox {
  margin-top: -28px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}
#users-title h3 {
  padding: 6px 0 6px 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
#users-title {} #users {
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="users-title">
  <h3 class="toggler">Список под заказ - от 14.02.2016</h3>
</div>
<div id="users">
  <div id="searchbox">
    <input class="search" placeholder="Что ищем?" type="text" />
  </div>
  <table style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody class="list">
      <tr>
        <td class="name" colspan="2" style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="color: #ff0000;">Список</span></strong>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="number">1</td>
        <td class="name">Имя</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="number">2</td>
        <td class="name">Имя1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script src="media/list.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="media/list.fuzzysearch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Поле #Number находится в форме обратной связи.

Comment: весь код с хтмл сюда

Comment: весь код с подключением скрипта в вопрос, а не комментарии.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Готово